# Confused about elvis's it

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I'm using ktor and for some reason, the elvis operator's `it` is the outer scope's `it` and not the left operand. Can someone help to explain?

[image]

Comment: they are not the same `it`

Comment: Can you help to explain why? shouldn't they both be the same ```it```? Sorry, I'm new to Kotlin

Comment: What do you not understand? The second `let` isn't bound to `jwt`, which would be null anyway.  So I'm guessing it falls back to applying `let` to object scope.  It's equivalent to `jwt?.let { /* code */} ?: this.let {/*code*/}`

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Also, don't present text as an image. See [ask].

Comment: Hmm I guess they call it an elvis because typing "null-coalescing operator" is tedious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code to the right of a `?:` is only called if the expression to the left of the `?:` evaluates to `null`. So your second `let` only gets called if `jwt` is null, or if the lambda of the first `let` returns null.

The code to the right of `?:` therefore is evaluated completely independently from the code to the left. You're calling `let` on whatever `this` is.

Your first `let` is called on `jwt`. The second `let` is called on whatever `this` is at that point. Notice there is no `.` before it. You're using the typical shortcut of omitting `this.` before a bare function call.

It is inadvisable to chain scope functions with `?:` because it is extremely error-prone and hard to read the code and interpret it correctly. One possible big pitfall is if your first lambda evaluates to `null`, you could be running both scope functions to the left and right of the `?:` inadvertantly.